# Moving a Vuetify calendar one from forward from a child/partner component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, calendar, components, vuetify.js

The Vuetify calendar uses the following to navigate:

`@click="$refs.calendar.prev()"`
`@click="$refs.calendar.next()"`

These commands work if you have them in the same file as the calendar. I'm using the [bottom (last) instance of the calendar](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/calendars) from the Vuetify docs, but I want the side panel (which I'm using as a Change Log as the calendar will be used for changing a diary/planner). `$refs.calendar` doesn't work in that component. I tried passing down the reference to the child component but `$refs` just comes through as undefined.

How can I move the calendar forward one month from a child component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

In your parent component, you call your child component, i called it `CalendarNav`. Inside, you'll have your calendar navigation buttons. You bind 2 events to it, `previousMonth` and `nextMonth`. When your parent component will receive `prevMonth` or `nextMonth` events, it will execute function passed to it.

```
<CalendarNav @prevMonth="$refs.calendar.prev()" @nextMonth="$refs.calendar.next()" />
```

and in you child component `CalendarNav`, you emit events when buttons are clicked, like this :

```
<v-btn @click="$emit('nextMonth')">
    Next
    <v-icon
      right
      dark
    >
      keyboard_arrow_right
    </v-icon>
  </v-btn>
```

and

```
<v-btn @click="$emit('prevMonth')">
    <v-icon
      dark
      left
    >
      keyboard_arrow_left
    </v-icon>
    Prev
  </v-btn>
```

[VueJS Doc about Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)